# My friends flight was cancelled but mine wasn’t, what can I do?

Tags: air-travel, cancellations

I wanted to fly to Spain over the next weekend with some friends. They wanted to fly on Thursday evening and I had to fly on Friday morning, because I have to work on Thursday and can't make it. Now my friends' flight has been cancelled due to strikes and I would be stuck in Spain alone. Is there anything I can do ?

We booked with the same airline(unfortunately Ryanair) but from different departure airports.

Comment: You can try to contact Ryanair, but you're basically at their mercy.

Comment: You could also check with your travel insurance provider, if they might reimburse you some or part of the trip. Appealing to Ryanair is usually pointless. They are cheap for a reason.

Comment: Do the travel. Traveling alone is not so bad. Probably not ideal (also because of such short term notification). Consider it just like the flight were cancelled at airport or other unpredictable nuisances.

Comment: Why can’t their flight be rescheduled by the airline? Or if they are getting full refunds can’t they rebook somewhere else on similar dates?

Comment: @HankyPanky, when the flights were canceled, Ryanair was under a lot of pressure of strikes, so there was not a lot of options to rebook. They needed all spaces for those passengers stuck away from home. Other companies were also quite fully booked and any tickets available would have been rather expensive. A later weekend would only work if all (so also OP) were getting their money back.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

While you can ask the airline, it is rather likely that they would not cancel and refund you the money, Ryanair is not known to be customer friendly. With other airlines and lots of people who need to be rebooked your chances are better.

If you as a group have taken out travel insurance it is there you should ask first. By individual insurance contracts I fear you will not be reimbursed, but you can try.

On the other hand, traveling alone can be a great experience so why not just go?

Answer (score 0):

Your friends could simply book a different flight. Presumably, their tickets were cancelled by the airlines, so they got their money back. Use that money (and probably some on top) to buy tickets on a different flight. There may even be availability on the flight you are taking.

Comment: that was in fact, what they ended up doing. I did't assume it would work since there are not much flights from my region to that particular region in spain and one of the airports here was closed due to strikes, but lucky for us it still worked.